# IPR assigment for freelance work

Tags: contracts

I've been asked to sign an IPR-Assignment by someone who is paying me to do developer work for them on a freelance basis. I'm new to all of this and I'm just unsure whether it's appropriate to sign such a document? I would imagine you would need to see the agreement to tell for sure but the description of 'software product' I feel isn't clear enough and I'm worried (because I don't know what I'm doing) about signing away more than intended.

If there's anyone with advice on this matter, I would much appreciate it.

Comment: This is very broad.  Apparently you have some concerns with some of the text of the document.  Why don't you post it, or at least paraphrase?  Otherwise, you are giving us nothing to work with.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I'm assuming by IPR, you mean "Intellectual Property Rights".

I am not a lawyer, but the short answer to this is get professional legal advice. Over the years, I have seen contracts that range from "the employer only has IPR over the specific products being developed" to "the employer owns IPR on ideas the employee has in his/her own free time".

At the risk of repeating, there really is no subsitute for having a lawyer read through the document and discuss the implications with you.

Also, in my experience, these things are almost always negotiable. So if there is something in there that you don't like, do not be afraid to ask for it to be changed.